# Background Check JS - Simple yet doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, background

I'm using Background Check JS to try and get some text on my website to change based on the background being light or dark. I can't get it to work on my site to made a minimal replica of it and still no dice:

```
<html>
<head>  
    <style>
        .background--light {
          color: black;
        }
        .background--dark {
          color: white;
        }
        .background--complex {
          color: gray;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.kennethcachia.com/background-check/scripts/background-check.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            BackgroundCheck.init({
            targets: '.target',
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://www.kennethcachia.com/background-check/images/6.jpg">
    <div style="position: fixed; top: 65%;" class="target">Why not white?</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also sometimes an "CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data." Error pops up in this demo sometimes?

I may have missed something trivial in this demo but I can't get it to work at all on my "full" version I'm trying to write.

Comment: As a wild guess - in your CSS only use a single hypen for selector names. The double hyphen indicates a predefined CSS variable (if that is the right terminology).

Comment: Hi jeff, the supplementary class attributes aren't even being added to the "target" classes by the JS, so the problem lies before the CSS